# Addition rule for probability proof $ P(A \cap B) = P(A)+ P(B)- P(A \cup B) $

Tags: probability

I can't seem to grasp this rule, since I believe A and B will cancel out (Venn diagram)
$$
P(A \cap B) 
= P(A)+ P(B)- P(A \cup B)
$$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: In what form do you think they might cancel out?

Comment: $P(A\cup B) = P(A\setminus B) + P(A\cap B) + P(B\setminus A)$, seen by the fact that the three (*compound*) sets on the right are disjoint and together make up all of $A\cup B$.  Then add and subtract $P(A\cap B)$ and recognize that $P(A\setminus B) + P(A\cap B)$ similarly equals $P(A)$ for the same reason.  Rearrange if you like and you are done.

Comment: $$A+B = P(A \cap B) $$  That's what I think is going on therefore wouldn't that result in 0?

Comment: Normally you would have the union on the left, intersection on the right (equivalent, add/subtract from both sides). Then read it as 'the probability of A or B occurring is the probability of A, plus the probability of B, minus the probability of both occurring simultaneously'. In real life: the probability of one team scoring at least 3 goals is the probability of Arsenal scoring at least 3, plus the probability of Brighton scoring at least 3, minus the probability of both teams scoring 3 or more.

Comment: @Parziva1 I do not understand your most recent comment.  You have events by themselves on the left with an addition symbol inbetween... an operation not generally appearing between events.  On the right you have a probability.  $A+B=P(A\cap B)$ does not make any sense.  Maybe you meant $P(A)+P(B)=P(A\cap B)$ but this also doesn't make much sense because, as you suggest, this would imply $P(A)=P(B)=P(A\cap B) = 0$, but that is irrelevant to the question of $P(A\cap B) = P(A)+P(B)\color{red}{-P(A\cup B)}$

Comment: @JMoravitz I sort of get where your coming from - I see my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't seem to grasp this rule, since I believe A and B will cancel out (Venn diagram)

The measure for the union equals the sum of the measures for each, minus the measure for the intersection (since you do not want to include the intersection twice).

So to measure $A\cup B$, we add the measure for $A$ to the measure for $B\smallsetminus A$ (that which is in $B$ but not in $A$).  However, the later is the measure for $B$ minus the measure for $A\cap B$.

---

Recalling that probability measure is additive for a union of *disjoint* sets:...

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(A\cup B)&=\mathsf P(A\cup(B\smallsetminus A))\\&=\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(B\smallsetminus A)\\&=\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(B\smallsetminus A)+(\mathsf P(A\cap B)-\mathsf P(A\cap B))\\&=\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P((B\smallsetminus A)\cup(A\cap B))-\mathsf P(A\cap B)\\&=\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(B)-\mathsf P(A\cap B)\end{align}$$

---

Then we just rearrange algebraically.  $$\therefore \mathsf P(A\cap B)=\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(B)-\mathsf P(A\cup B)$$

The measure of the intersection equals the sum of measure for each, minus the measure for the union … since the sum of the measure for each includes the measure for the intersecton twice, while the measure for the union includes it but once.